# Hide and Show toggle are not working

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have code to have a hidden div become shown when another div before it is clicked. However, the code doesn't seem to be working nd when I inspect element in firefox, I dint even see the event listener attached.

This is the code

```
                                 <div class="col-sm-4 uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-scale-up toggle2" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-scale-up', repeat: false}" id="DivMenuMain">
                                <div class="wiwet-feature_item1 menu-individual" id="divMenuInside1a" runat="server">
                                    <div class="wpm_feature_icon itemName">NAME</div>
                                    <div class="background-menu-pic"></div>
                                    <div class="menuSquarePrice">$9.99</div>
                                    <div class="homePage3s">DESCRIPTION TEXT</div>
                                    <div class="desertToo">Add A Dessert</div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="wiwet-feature_item1 menu-individual hidden2" id="divMenuInside1b" runat="server">
                                    <div class="wpm_feature_icon greedies">Ingredients</div>
                                    <div class="menuSquareNutrition">Nutritional</div>
                                    <div class="prepTime">Best if prepared by x days</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                             <script type="text/javascript">
                             function() {
                                 $('.current').not(this).toggleClass('current').next('.hidden2').slideFadeToggle();
                                 $(this).toggleClass('current').next().slideFadeToggle(500, function() {
                                     var this_element = $(this);
                                     setTimeout(function() {
                                         var scroll_to = this_element.prev('.toggle2').offset().top;
                                         $('html, body').animate({
                                             scrollTop: scroll_to
                                         }, 500);
                                     }, 500);
                                 });
                             }
                           </script>
```

Comment: I actually want the divs to not toggle per-say, but actually flip around on eachother like a piece of paper being flipped over.
So in essence hidden2 is actually the backside of toggle2

Comment: Something like [This](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)?

Comment: kind of yes...But I want it to be clicked and remain on the flip sides unless clicked again...not hovered off of

Comment: There is an example for "toggle" flip further down in the post. If you understand the logic of hover, it's simple to apply it as toggle.

Comment: I got that to work, however it is acting weird on mobile. It simply reverses the div and doesn't display the "back"

Comment: Maybe you're missing some browser prefixes. Your mobile browser probably does not support some of the things you did to the divs. You can check the support across browsers [Here](http://caniuse.com/).

Comment: What I'd really like to do is turn this to an onclick event rather than a hover.

Comment: Ok no problem tell me what div you want to appear/disappear and I'll post the fiddle with the answer.

Comment: I simply changed the psuedo class to 'active' instead of 'hover', and added an onclick instead of "ontouchstart".

Comment: That could work. Check out my answer now, I just updated it to what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request something like this should work for you.

### [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/fobaxi/edit?css,output)

I used this [post](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) as starting point.

Firstly we remove all the actions correlating with **:hover**.

Then I added the css response (transformation) I wanted in a class called **flip** that I add to the container using a js function, that's triggered by clicking a button.

So when the container gets the class flip we have the following style applied to all of its contents:

```
.flip-container.flip > .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```js
function flipIt() {
  $(".flip-container").toggleClass("flip");
}
```

```css
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 200px;
  height: 253px;
}
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container.flip > .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}
button{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="flipIt()">Toggle</button>
  
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q1hXv6d.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q1hXv6d.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the flip feature though. There should be a parameter to pass in to the flip CSS that does it on a click instead of hover, no? Shouldn't this be effected this.classList.toggle('hover') if I change 'hover' to something else? I cannot seem to gain any insight from the "ontouchstart" anywhere on the web.

Comment: I've updated my answer, this version should be satisfactory.